# Kolmogorov zero-one law in continuous time?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_t : t \geq 0)$ be a stochastic process. Is it necessarily the case that

$$P (\limsup_{t \geq 0} X_t \leq a) \in \{ 0,1\}$$

as it is in discrete time? If some conditions are needed on the process, what are these?

Many thanks for your help.

EG What if $X_t$ is a Feller process.

Comment: How about taking $X_t = a -1, \forall t$ with proba $0.5$ and $X_t = a+1, \forall t$ with proba $0.5$?

Comment: with probability $1$ this would have $\limsup = a+1$, and so $P(\limsup X_t \leq c) = 0$ for $c<a+1$ and $1$ otherwise.... :S

Comment: It rather depends on whether the $X_s,X_t$ are independent (an assumption for the Kolmogorov zero-one law) or all equal.

Comment: @Frank It seems to be that with probability $0.5$, $\limsup X_t = a + 1$ and with probability $0.5$, $\limsup X_t = a - 1$

Comment: @LiuGang I misinterpreted your comment, I was thinking of them as all being independent, whereas you meant they really are all exactly the same.

Comment: Even in discrete time, plenty of non pathological processes have non constant limsup.

Comment: @Did not if you assume independence. c.f. page 46 of Williams....

Comment: Independent processes are a **very** restricted type of Feller process, wouldn't you say?